# Sort list of lists based on date and first element

Tags: python, sorting

```py
ArrayData = [['a', 'ad', '02/10/2021  7:39:19 am', 'Rank:1'],
             ['b', 'db', '02/10/2021 6:25:20 am', 'Rank:2'],
             ['a', 'sd', '02/10/2021  5:39:19 am', 'Rank:3'],
             ['b', 'esas', '02/10/2021 6:25:20 am', 'Rank:1'],
             ['a', 'aser', '02/10/2021  9:39:19 am', 'Rank:2'],
             ['d', 'ssss', '02/10/2021  11:39:19 am', 'Rank:1']]
```

The script should

1. Sort the same group (eg. sort group 'a' first, followed by group 'b', 'c', 'd') base on the time. More recent times and dates have higher ranks.
2. Update the "rank" in each subarray

Expected output:

```py
[['d', 'ssss', '02/10/2021  11:39:19 am', 'Rank:1'],
 ['b', 'esas', '03/10/2021 6:25:20 am', 'Rank:2'],
 ['b', 'db', '02/10/2021 6:25:20 am', 'Rank:1'],
 ['a', 'aser', '02/10/2021  9:39:19 am', 'Rank:3'],
 ['a', 'ad', '02/10/2021  7:39:19 am', 'Rank:2'],
 ['a', 'sd', '02/10/2021  5:39:19 am', 'Rank:1']]
```

This is the current script I wrote

```py
import operator
result = sorted(ArrayData, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

May I know how to improve it?

Comment: You're still sorting the dates based on the raw strings, you need to parse them

Comment: Why `['d', 'ssss', '11-04-20', 'Rank:1']` is the first one in the output?

Comment: *Update the "rank" in each subarray* - can you explain that? (As for now - my solution increment the Rank by 1)

Comment: It's pretty clear by inspection of the desired output: the "rank" corresponds to the how recent the date is in each group. More recent dates have higher ranks, but each group is ranked only with others in the group.

Comment: @ddjohn, yup, this is what I want

Comment: @Dani Mesejo, Because I want the output sequence as "d","c","b", and each group rank according to the date( recent date has higher rank).

Comment: Are you satisfied with either of the answers provided thus far? If so, don't forget to accept one so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue!

Answer (score 1):

Note that this converts your datetime strings to `datetime.datetime` objects. This may or may not be desirable, but is at least recommended if you plan on doing any other operations involving those dates. If you really want them as strings, see the commented line of code.

Note also that I'm assuming that your dates are `dd/mm/yyyy`. If they are `mm/dd/yyyy` instead, you'll need to switch the `%d` and `%m` in `DATETIME_FORMAT`.

```py
import datetime
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter as get


# Assumes day/month/year, switch %d and %m if not
DATETIME_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"


def parse_datetimes(data: list) -> list:
    result = []
    for first, second, timestamp, rank in data:
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, DATETIME_FORMAT)
        result.append([first, second, timestamp, rank])
    return result


def custom_sort(data: list) -> list:
    # Convert datetime strings to datetime objects, then sort by first element
    sorted_data = sorted(parse_datetimes(data), key=get(0), reverse=True)

    # Re-rank each group sorted by date
    result = []
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_data, key=get(0)):
        ranked_group = []
        sorted_group = sorted(group, key=get(2))
        for rank, (*item, _) in enumerate(sorted_group, 1):
            # item[2] = item[2].strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)
            ranked_group.append([*item, f"Rank:{rank}"])
        result.extend(ranked_group[::-1])
    return result
```

Demo:

```py
>>> custom_sort(ArrayData)
[['d', 'ssss', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 11, 39, 19), 'Rank:1'],
 ['b', 'esas', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 6, 25, 20), 'Rank:2'],
 ['b', 'db', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 6, 25, 20), 'Rank:1'],
 ['a', 'aser', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 9, 39, 19), 'Rank:3'],
 ['a', 'ad', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 7, 39, 19), 'Rank:2'],
 ['a', 'sd', datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 5, 39, 19), 'Rank:1']]
```

Comment: What if need to consider both time (hour/minute) and date?

Comment: @liuxu see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions seemed too complicated to me. If you want you can use string comparison without resorting to `datetime`s.

Here's a custom solution I rigged together that seems to give the desired output:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
from typing import DefaultDict, List


array_data = [['d', 'ssss', '11-04-20', 'Rank:1'],
              ['a', 'ad', '10-13-20', 'Rank:1'],
              ['b', 'db', '12-13-20', 'Rank:2'],
              ['a', 'sd', '05-13-20', 'Rank:3'],
              ['b', 'esas', '12-14-20', 'Rank:1'],
              ['a', 'aser', '12-13-20', 'Rank:2']]


final_array = []
group_to_data: DefaultDict[str, List[List[str]]] = defaultdict(list)

for data in array_data:
    group_to_data[data[0]].append(data)


def sort_fn(x):
    """Sort by group, then by date"""
    month, day, year = x[2].split('-')
    return f'{year}{month}{day}'


for _, data in sorted(group_to_data.items(), reverse=True):
    # sorts sub-list for each group
    data.sort(key=sort_fn)

    # iterating over data in reverse order, since that's how we want it in
    # final result
    for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1):
        new_rank = f"Rank:{i + 1}"
        item = data[i]
        item[-1] = new_rank
        final_array.append(item)

pprint(final_array)
```

Comment: The sublists are already grouped by the first element via your `defaultdict`. I don't think returning `x[0]` from `sort_fn()` is necessary since `sort_fn()` is already only being run on data grouped by the first element. I'd also suggest `for _, data` if you're not planning to use the `group` iterator variable anywhere in the loop body.

Comment: ah, good catch on both counts! will update the answer with those corrections shortly.